# Kotlin new Fragment from Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to open a new fragment from the current fragment's RecyclerView Adapter.But i don't know how to set onClickListener.. Here is my code

```
internal class ContentAdapter constructor (private var dataList: ArrayList<DataList>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val manager = activity.supportFragmentManager // I cannot resolve activity here 
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        val book = IndividualBook()
        transaction.add(android.R.id.content, book, "IndividualBook")
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        holder!!.bind(dataList)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(DataList: ArrayList<DataList>){
            val dataList = DataList[adapterPosition]
            itemView.itemTitle.text = dataList.title
            Glide.with(itemView.context).load(dataList.image).into(itemView.itemImage)
            itemView.regPrice.text = dataList.regPrice
            itemView.regPrice.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            itemView.splPrice.text = dataList.splPrice
        }
    }
}
```

Help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to create a new fragment when an item in the adapter is clicked?

Comment: Yes ... exactly... the clicking function is working fine... but i dnt know to pass the new fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few solutions:

1. Kotlin defaults all classes to `static`. You have to opt-in to them being `inner` classes. Put the class inside of an Activity, and add the `inner` modifier to the class:

   ```
   internal inner class ContentAdapter constructor (private var dataList: ArrayList<DataList>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener {
   ```
2. Keep the ContentAdapter `static`, but pass the `activity` in through the constructor:

   ```
   internal class ContentAdapter(
           private val activity: AppCompatActivity,
           private var dataList: ArrayList<DataList>
   ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener {
   ```

It looks like you probably aren't familiar with the ways that Kotlin differs from Java and defaults you to writing better code. It might help for you to read through the Kotlin documentation in entirety. It's not very long. I also recommend Kotlin Koans which are coding exercises JetBrains provides to practice Kotlin.

Kotlin is a huge improvement over Java :-) Don't let this discourage you!

(By the way, it looks like you can probably make your `dataList` a `val`. `val` is always preferred over `var` when the reference is `final`.)

Answer (score 2):

It will be better to use callback to activity to navigate to new fragment.

Change constructor to

```
internal class ContentAdapter constructor (private var dataList: ArrayList<DataList>,private var callback:()->Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener
```

Then inside

`override fun onClick(v: View?)`

put

`callback.invoke();`

Activity will set adapter by

```
val adapter = ContentAdapter(datalist)
{ // Code to navigate to new fragment

}
```

Comment: I disagree with this approach. It's better to assume the adapter is part of the View code. I'm not sure there is any advantage of trying to separate it out, as the adapter deals with creating and configuring the view anyways. The only reason to do what you are saying is if you wanted to reuse this adapter on multiple screens, which I discourage.

Comment: It's not good to put change in screens like new fragment or anew activity inside adapter. All the change of screen should be part of activity/ fragment. It's easy for debug as well as change in flow. Moreover adapter reuse will also be possible

Answer (score 1):

```
internal class ContentAdapter (private val activity: Activity, private var dataList: ArrayList<DataList>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener
```

You need to pass the activity in your constructor.
And a nice bonus tip for kotlin: 
If you have only one primary constructor you don't have to write the "constructor" prefix

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class ContentAdapter (private val activity: AppCompatActivity, private var dataList: ArrayList<DataList>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder>(), View.OnClickListener
```

When you have the activity you can access the manager

You need to pass the activity in the constructor 
And a kotlin tip if you have only one primary constructor you don't have to write it.

Comment: Where does it fail?

Comment: Sorry my bad you need to pass AppCompatActivity to get the support fragment manager

Answer (score 0):

Use Onclick as alternative of onClickListener, you can use onClick like this.

```
 itemView.regPrice.onClick {
/ * your action */
}
```